# Telling to a different person of a very bad experience of someone

Tags: united-kingdom, international, students

A graduate student in the UK told me about a really grave experience that they had in a different country. This experience has a long-lasting effect on their life and studies. However, I am not 100% sure that this experience really happened. I have a colleague working at the university that the student attended (and where this bad thing happened). Can I tell to this colleague of mine about the experience of the student? Is this legal?

PS. The reason why I was thinking of sharing this info with this colleague, is that, I believe, the colleague can either confirm or refute this information. (Unfortunately, I found the student giving me information that was not true on a couple of occasions)

Comment: While the legal answers to this question may be interesting, you should consider ethical/moral concerns as well. If your friend was lying, or even if (s)he told the truth and you misunderstood him/her, this could cause significant, needless damage to an innocent person's reputation.

Comment: In all likelihood there is a department at your university exists (among other reasons) to help faculty navigate ethical questions involving students. They are your best resource if you are unsure how to proceed.

Comment: What is your relationship to this graduate student?  In other words, why do you hesitate at all to confirm something that you have evidence could be a lie based on previous untruths?  And what would you do with the information once you confirm it one way or the other?

Comment: Why would it be useful for the collage to confirm or refute the information?  It's not clear what your interest in the student's experience is.

Comment: Does this information affect your professional obligations? E.g. if it was part of an explanation of why work hadn't been completed. That would likely change the calculus because it means that it was the University that was being told in confidence, rather than just you. So seeking information from a colleague in the same institution would likely be allowable, provided you made it clear that the info was confidential.

Answer (score 0):

### Duty of Confidence

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

A [duty of confidence](https://www.alrc.gov.au/publication/for-your-information-australian-privacy-law-and-practice-alrc-report-108/15-federal-information-laws/obligations-of-confidence/) can arise in contract (not applicable here) or in equity.

> The obligation arises where information with the necessary quality of confidence is imparted in circumstances importing an obligation of confidence. Such circumstances will exist where the information is imparted on the understanding that it is to be treated by the confidant on a limited basis, or where the confidant ought to have realised that in all the circumstances the information was to be treated in such a way. Breach of the obligation occurs where there is an unauthorised use, not only where there is unauthorised disclosure, of the information.

So, if the information was given to you in confidence, you can neither use it (e.g. to make enquires of your colleague) nor disclose it. The test for whether it is given in confidence is the reasonable person test - would a reasonable person in the position of the confidant consider that the confider wished that confidence should be kept considering all the circumstances?

This duty can be supervened by another legal obligation such as if you are a law enforcement officer or a mandatory discloser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, Dale! How can I know (judge) whether this information was given to me in confidence? In fact, the student told this to me on two distinct occasions...

Comment: What is considered *unauthorized use?* Would it be for instance some sort of action by an employer or school?

Comment: @Michael use that isn’t authorized by the person who gave you the information